# Codeigniter pagination is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to do pagination in codeigniter.  Pagination is coming in the view page, but when I  try to click on next link I am getting this error:

```
The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.
```

and this is my url while click on next button

```
http://localhost/indianeers/pages/load_country/&per_page=2.
```

Please help me to do this pagination. I have been struggling for 3 days.

I have seen this in config.php

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

Should i change this code?

Comment: in config there is permitted_uri_chars.Look in that

Comment: include your code with question

Comment: hi @AdarshMPallickal .. can make it clear ... i have seen this in config .php $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-'; should i change this code  ?

Comment: add & to that permitted_uri_chars

Comment: then what should i pass ... ?@AdarshMPallickal

Comment: sorry you can pass.Are you try with my code

Comment: First thing, I don't see any reason why 'per_page' get into the url, it should be a config item, not url's. Can you share your pagination configuration settings so that I could help more? You could also check my own written tutorial on codeigniter pagiation to see in detailed and a demo as well: http://codesamplez.com/development/codeigniter-pagination-tutorial. Hope those will help you as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you pass & with URI and that is not included in the config page.

replace ur code with below code in config

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-&';
```

Answer (score 0):

permitted_uri_chars are the characters that CodeIgniter accepts in your URI.The default value is set to something like.

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:&_\-';
```

By default only these are allowed: a-z 0-9~%.:_-

Leave blank to allow all characters -- but only if you are insane.

Try this-
Add `%3D` to  `$config['permitted_uri_chars']`